# f2py fails to run - error in CompaqVisualFCompiler, with no compaq compiler installed

Tags: python, windows, fortran, mingw, f2py

I'm trying to use f2py (under anaconda 2, windows 7 64bit, python 2.7.13) but I run into the following error repeatedly, even when simply trying to list available compilers:

```
(C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2) C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\fortran>f2py -c --help-fco
mpiler

(C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2) C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\fortran>call "C:\Users\UserName\
Anaconda2\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\Scripts\\f2py
.py" -c --help-fcompiler
Unexpected ValueError in C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\dist
utils\fcompiler\compaq.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\Scripts\\f2py.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line
 648, in main
    run_compile()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line
 633, in run_compile
    setup(ext_modules=[ext])
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", l
ine 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 467, in parse_co
mmand_line
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 576, in _parse_c
ommand_opts
    func()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\con
fig_compiler.py", line 15, in show_fortran_compilers
    show_fcompilers(dist)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\_
_init__.py", line 882, in show_fcompilers
    load_all_fcompiler_classes()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\_
_init__.py", line 740, in load_all_fcompiler_classes
    __import__ (module_name)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\c
ompaq.py", line 57, in <module>
    class CompaqVisualFCompiler(FCompiler):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\c
ompaq.py", line 100, in CompaqVisualFCompiler
    raise e
ValueError: [u'path', u'include']

(C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2) C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\fortran>
```

I've installed minGW for anaconda (via `conda install mingw`), so it *should* detect and run that. I'm not too sure but it seems like it's trying to find the compaq one instead and failing at that? Here's the relevant section of compaq.py (line 100 is the final line):

```
if sys.platform=='win32':
        from numpy.distutils.msvccompiler import MSVCCompiler

        try:
            m = MSVCCompiler()
            m.initialize()
            ar_exe = m.lib
        except DistutilsPlatformError:
            pass
        except AttributeError:
            msg = get_exception()
            if '_MSVCCompiler__root' in str(msg):
                print('Ignoring "%s" (I think it is msvccompiler.py bug)' % (msg))
            else:
                raise
        except IOError:
            e = get_exception()
            if not "vcvarsall.bat" in str(e):
                print("Unexpected IOError in", __file__)
                raise e
        except ValueError:
            e = get_exception()
            if not "path']" in str(e):
                print("Unexpected ValueError in", __file__)
                raise e
```

Comment: Do you have a Fortran Compiler? Which one? How did you install it? Do you have MINGW or Compaq or what?

Comment: I've installed mingw for anaconda (installed by `conda install mingw`), I also have the intel 18 compiler installed but am not using it here because I thought getting the environment variables set up would cause more potential problems than just using mingw. I definitely don't have the compaq compiler.